# Launch icon doesn't look as intended // flutter_launcher_icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, icons

Solved; see below.

I'm trying to export a logo from XD and set it up as my app icon with flutter_launcher_icons (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons), but it doesn't look like intended. I'm not even sure, if he issue is flutter related or if I'm making mistakes when exporting from XD. So I'm a bit lost.

Here is what it looks like, what I tried and what it should look like:

- In the screen where I can flip betwen apps, the icon doesn't fill the circle for the app icon, but is put there as a rectangle:

[image]

- Same in the drawer with all the apps:

[image]

I tried using a square with nothing but the background color and set it as icon background in pubspec.yaml:

```
  adaptive_icon_background: '.\assets\icons\logo_icon_background.png'
```

But that then looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: It stays the same, if I also specify the adaptive icon foregroud (  adaptive_icon_foreground: '.\assets\icons\logo_launch_dummy.png')

For reference, this is the look I'm after (wihtout context like the shadow etc.):

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This looks like an issue you should raise with the package's developer on their GitHub issues: https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons/issues

Answer (score 0):

For Posterity: It worked out when I created a new image file with the logo path and the background color all in one png, size 512x512. Then just doing this in pubspec.yaml was enough:

```
    dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.9.2"

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: '.\assets\icons\logo_launch_dummy.png'
```

So the issue was with me exporting things from XD without enough care for the dimensions.